# Add PHP to style.css in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to achieve something relatively simple, along these lines:

if user is NOT logged in, add this to style.css:

`div.em-booking {
       display: none;
   }`

if user IS logged in:
   don't modify style.css

So I'm suspecting that a bit of CSS+PHP along the lines of this will do the trick:

`div.em-booking {
    <?php
       if (!is_user_logged_in() )
       echo 'display: none';
    ?>
}`

I found this: [Accessing global variable in "CSS" (style.php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796542/accessing-global-variable-in-css-style-php/5582616#5582616)
which looked very useful - just @import the additional embedded_style.php file into the style.css file. But this seemingly did not work. I see that that post is quite old (2011), and maybe Wordpress has changed sufficiently that this will no longer work.

I have read about many method of changing the .htaccess file to force a website to read a PHP file instead of CSS file, but will this technique work with a Wordpress theme + child theme site, which has two style.css files (the parent theme + the child theme)?

As it happens, my Wordpress site's parent theme has (I suspect) been abandoned by its developer, so it's unlikely that there will ever be updates to it, so I suppose I could modify the parent theme's style.css to become style.php and add my modifications directly in there. But I'd prefer to leave the parent style.css file alone.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be very welcome! Apologies if this has been answered before somewhere in Stackoverflow, but I could not find anything specific to Wordpress when it comes to adding PHP to CSS; most suggestions involve modifying a static site's HTML, which (I assume) wouldn't work with Wordpress due to the many files accessing the style.css.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Bit risky hoping that CSS hides something you don't want non-members to see. It will still be in the DOM.

Comment: have you tried something like this? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_user_logged_in-change-css-value

Comment: @dwhite.me agreed... in the past i've unhidden things to get what i want.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121453/change-css-for-logged-in-users

Comment: Thanks everyone for all those incredibly quick and useful replies! A lot to go on...I'm working on it now and will no doubt be back with more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Inserting any PHP code to CSS is impossible. You have to do the other way around:

```
if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    echo '<div style="display: none"></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div></div>';
}
```

But this is not secure because anyone will see it when looking in HTML source. Do this instead:

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    echo '<div>you are logged in</div>';
} else {
    //show nothing or a message that someone is not logged
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just target your code based on the CSS class? Assuming your theme supports appending to the body classes which is generally a default and best practice, you should have `logged-in` at your disposal.

Example: `<body class="home page page-id-2238 page-template page-template-template-home page-template-template-home-php logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">`

```
.logged-in .em-booking {
       display: block; /* whatever your set default is */
   }
.em-booking {
       display: none;
   }
```

Comment: This totally worked perfectly! As for security, I'm not that bothered if the users can delve into the guts of the page and see the member-only content; I want to hide it from non-logged-in-users mainly for aesthetic reasons.

I'll still probably have a go at combining some CSS and PHP just out of interest.

Thank you Aibrean!

Comment: Or you could enqueue the 'logged in only' css file only when logged in.